# Creating one common model`s field both for email and telegram nickname depending on user's authorization way in Django(DRF)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have been struggling with a task for two days and can not find an appropriate solution, so I would be very grateful for any help. The task is as follows: when a user logs in via Yandex/Google (I use `drf_social_auth2`), upon saving them in the database, the value of the `username` field becomes the user's email address. However, when logging in via Telegram, the value of the same `username` field should be the user's Telegram nickname. The first part is implemented through the `USERNAME_FIELD` attribute and the `get_username` method. The question is, how can we accomplish the second part, so that the `username` equals the Telegram nickname?

One option I considered was using the `username` field from parent `AbstractUser` model to store the necessary value depending on the method, but there's an issue with the fact that drf_social_oauth2, which I use for authorization, saves the email as the email value, and I can't find ways to make it save email to `username` field.
Here is the code for my `User`:

```
class User(AbstractUser, TimeStampedUUIDModel, PermissionsMixin):

    # First and last name do not cover name patterns around the globe
    name = CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    email = EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("User")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Users")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.email}"

    @property
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name
```

I would be grateful for any advice, from customizing `drf_social_auth2` to make some sort of dynamic `USERNAME_FIELD`.